# The use of java `indexOf` for `float[]`

Tags: java, indexof

In Java, using `java.util.Arrays`, the following codes:

```
float[] arr = {(float)0.2, (float)4.5};
Float[] brr = {new Float(0.2), new Float(4.5)};
Float x = new Float(4.5);
float y = (float)4.5;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(x));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(y));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(brr).indexOf(x));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(brr).indexOf(y));
```

gives

```
-1
-1
1
1
```

My question: How can I search for the index of 4.5 in the array `arr`?

I thought that `Arrays.asList(arr)` makes a list of objects from `arr` but it does not behave like the other array, `brr`.

Comment: You can loop the list and use the Wrapped equals to find the index, I'm looking for the reason why your code inst working

Comment: AndrewSun answer is the reason the code didnt worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` takes a `T...` as the argument. When the parameter is an array of objects, it is passed as if you wrote `Arrays.asList(new Float(0.2), new Float(4.5))`.

In your second case, the parameter is an array of primitives. Here, the Java compiler decides to treat the entire array as a single object. Hence, you will be passing an array containing a single element, the array of floats.

To confirm this, try the following:

`Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(arr) // returns 0`

Since the method is typed as `<T> List<T> asList(T...ts)` only the second of this statements are allowed:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.<Float>asList(arr).indexOf(x)); //Error
    System.out.println(Arrays.<Float>asList(brr).indexOf(x)); //List<Float>
```

The first one of primitive types cannot be typed as Float at the argument.

The statement to convert it to a List is the following:

```
 List<float[]> l = Arrays.<float[]>asList(arr); //The array is the only index in the List
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes It behaves like this. The problem is you do not create arr as Float object array. Instead you make the array of primitive.

Try this code

```
Float[] arr = {(float)0.2, (float)4.5};
Float[] brr = {new Float(0.2), new Float(4.5)};
float x = 0.2f;
float y = (float)4.5;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(x));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).indexOf(y));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(brr).indexOf(x));
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(brr).indexOf(y));
```

This code will provide you your desired output

Comment: The array arr already exists as an array of floats. Do I have to convert all of its elements?

Comment: Either you need to cast it or you need to define it like this
Float[] arr = {0.2f, 4.5f};

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.asList(arr)`, if `arr` is an array of primitives, creates **a list of a single element**, which is the array itself.

I.e.:

```
    float[] arr = {(float)0.2, (float)4.5};

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).get(0).getClass().getSimpleName());
      // Prints "float[]"
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr).size());
      // Prints "1"
```